# How to loop through a list of static values (constants) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

How to loop through a fixed (development time) list of values in JavaScript?

In Perl, I'd do:

```
for my $item ('foo', 'bar', 'baz') {
```

which would run the loop with `foo`, `bar` and `baz` in `$item` (one each loop run).

JavaScript could do:

```
for (item in new Array('foo', 'bar', 'baz')) {
```

but that would make `item` contain `0`, `1` and `2`, not the values.

Copy&paste the source for each item would be an option, but a very bad one in terms of maintenance.

Another option would be

```
var items = new Array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
for (i in items) {
    var item = items[i];
```

But that's also bad code as it defines a structure (Array) with lots of overhead where none is needed.

Comment: Use `for (item of ...)` instead: [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: what is the expected output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `i in items` use `let i of items`, this is because `in` gets attribute names, but `of` actually iterates through the array properly.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed it to be that easy but didn't find anything on the web.

Answer (score 3):

A good option is to use the `forEach` like:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].forEach(function(item){ console.log(item); })
```

for loops only work well with `object object`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach